# what is the action to hear in receiver for alarm clock android

Tags: android, filter, android-intent, alarm, receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.AReceiver">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
  <action android:name="alarm_killed" />
  <action android:name="cancel_snooze" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is my code in manifest and this is what I use to hear in my receiver on OnReceive(). I want to do something in the moment when you change your or set your native alarm clock in the android and this is not working. 
When I add for example this:

```
action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>

action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
```

it is working if you set the time. So my broadcast receiver is good.

What to set in the intent filter to trigger (listen) when alarm is set?

I'm developing for android 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my code in manifest

This is not part of the Android SDK. Anything with `com.android` in it is not part of the Android SDK. It may not work on some devices, if the alarm clock application is replaced or changed by the device manufacturer. It may not work on future versions of Android. Do not use this.

> What to set in the intent filter to trigger (listen) when alarm is set?

There are no documented and supported broadcasts from the alarm clock application. More importantly, there simply is no broadcast when an alarm is set.